# Scrolling Navigation Bar without JS

Tags: html, css, navigation, scroll

I saw a great navigation menu at a product webite of [Sony](http://www.sony.co.uk/electronics/cyber-shot-compact-cameras/dsc-rx100m3?cpint=hot_1_DSC-RX100M3_newProduct#product_details_default).
What happens: If you scroll down the Navigation changes between "Features", "Specifications", "Reviews", ... .
How can i make this and can i make this without JS? OR What should I search for? (Note: I have researched but don't know how to call this effect).
Thank you.

Comment: What makes you think it's not done with JS? Because it is....

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this would be possible, at least not to change the menu when scrolling. You could make a menu like this by jumping to targets (`a href="#a"` goes to `div id="a"`) then using the `:target` CSS selector.

Answer (score 0):

Or, if you don't like Florija's clean solution you can look for ScrollIntoView() from Javascript

Answer (score 0):

Twitter Bootstrap - it's called scrollspy... but it uses JavaScript. There is no way to do this without it. It's really easy to implement though.

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#scrollspy

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it has to be done with JavaScript / JQuery. If you're looking for a good start, take a look online to find some scripts already made. GitHub hosts amazing scripts and are generally for free use.

I'll help you out with this little bit of code.

The first thing is to make a wrapper, and then inside that wrapper, you want "main" and "nav". I do this format to reduce scripting in Javascript. Then in CSS, mark them up, and style them. Make sure that nav is position: fixed and that you set it from top:0px. Then for the main, set it to be top:(how many pixels you used for your navbar's height). Do not set the main to be fixed. Then you're good to go. The navbar will always be on top and then everything below it scrolls. I use this system quit a bit to avoid scripting. You're next bet is to then take a look at Florija's solution and then spice up some JQuery on top of it.

```
<body>

<div id="wrapper">

<div id="nav"></div>
<div id="main"></div>

</div>

</body>

body {
    /*blabla*/
}
#wrapper {
    /*blabla*/
}
#nav {
    position:fixed;
    height: 40px;
    top:0
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color:black;
    /*blablabla*/
}
#main {
    margin: 0 auto;
    min-height: 1200px;
    max-height: 100%;
    blackground-color: cyan;
    top: 40px;
    position: relative;
}
```

**AND IF YOU WANT THE EXACT CODE YOU NEED:** If you're looking for something like that, then this is your **exact** solution. Use JQuery waypoints!

http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/

Its a script that upon hitting a selector (on the website, it would be a class) it would perform a certain code. In this instance, it would be to either .remove(previous div and its content) and then .append(new div with new content) for your nav bar. As you can see, its crude, and simple, but for getting the point across it gets the job done.

For example

```
$('.firstwaypoint').waypoint(function() {
$('#navbar1').remove();
$('#nav').append("<div id="navbar2">content</div>");
});

<div id="nav">
<div id="navbar1">content</div>
</div>
```

Then it transforms it into:

```
<div id="nav">
<div id="navbar2">the new content goes here</div>
</div>
```

This is hypothetical code, and I did not test it. I'm assuming it works because this is pretty basic jquery.